# How can i create responsive text with javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I created a label with a number shown in it and I now want to make this number responsive to the GUI.
How can I do that? Here is my number with its current font-size.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("12");
label.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 35));
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean with *"to make this number responsive to the GUI"*? This could mean making the label vanish as soon as a button is clicked of changing any layout parameter of the label on any event of the GUI...

Comment: if i start the application in a different window-size the size of the number should match the window. At the moment the size of the number stays 35 all the time and is therfore too big for a smaller window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change values or params of this label you must use one of avelible javaFx controls: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/jfxpub-ui_controls.htm

For each control you have onActionListners functions where you can make changes.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Anchorpane,HBOX etc. are responsive in nature.Put the label inside a HBOX.

Hope this help.